# React Hooks TypeError: products.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, axios, array.prototype.map

Im new to react. Im getting this error products.map is not a function. I didnt get any errors related to .map function before but today it suddenly appeared. Can somebody pls help me fix this ?

```
import SingleProduct from "./SingleProduct";
import axios from "axios";
import { Container, Grid, Grow } from "@material-ui/core";

const Products = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = React.useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);
  const classes = useStyles();

  const getData = () => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:4000/api/products")
      .then((res) => {
        setProducts(res.data);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  React.useEffect(getData, []);
  return (
    <div>
        <Container>
          <Grow in>
            <Grid container spacing={6}>
              {products.map((product, index) => (
                <SingleProduct key={index} product={product} />
              ))}
            </Grid>
          </Grow>
        </Container>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Products;
```

Comment: it happens because products is not an array. since your initial state is an array, your res.data is not returning an array, most likely it's an object. you need to check what res.data returns

Comment: Can you log `res` just before you call setProducts? Also log `products`, please. The error implies you're setting it to something that isn't an array.

Comment: console.log(res) is giving me this {data: "<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head>
config: {url: "http://localhost:4000/api/products", method: "get", headers: {…}, baseURL: "http://localhost:4000/api/", transformRequest: Array(1), …}. Something like that

Comment: console.log(products) giving me this <!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/> . something like that

Comment: `res.data` seems to return an HTML document instead of a JSON. Is there a problem in the backend while fetching, like some kind of error?

Comment: Im getting no problems in the backend. It's showing Connected to mongodb. No app crashing errors or something like that.

Comment: this looks like an error sent from your backend but with a success status since it didn't catch by your promise.

Comment: It was running fine before but today I tried to deploy this on heroku and after that it stopped working.

Comment: We understand that it worked fine before, but the fact is that it no longer does. So console out the res.data inside `.then((res) => {` and see what comes back from the axios call.

Comment: The data return from server that you said `{data: "<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head> config: {url: "localhost:4000/api/products", method: "get", headers: {…}, baseURL: "localhost:4000/api", transformRequest: Array(1), …}`. It is not an array so it does not have `map` function. You have to check your backend server.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add an other protection at line 43 =>  https://github.com/muneebghani/semproject/blob/master/client/src/components/products/Products.js

```
) : products && (products.length === 0) ? (
  toast.error("Error: There are no products in DB", {
    position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER,
    toastId: "",
    transition: Slide,
  })
```

Comment: Will do later, and that's not causing any errors so try to give me a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your then, you should first validate `res.data` is an array.

```js
if(Array.isArray(res.data)) { 
    setProducts(res.data) 
} else { 
    throw new Error (“data invalid”)
}
```

The actual solution seems to be resolving the issue with your response. Regardless of this, it’s good to validate you’ve gotten the right response on the front end.

Comment: I also read through this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44749205/react-axios-calls-to-express-api-in-heroku-deployment Not sure if the body parser would be useful here?